# Add SharePoint list items from hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

anyone out there knows if it's possible to add items to a SP list from a hyperlink?
I would like to have user clicking on a hyperlink that will create and save an item in the list.
something like: 
http://www.SP.com/listname/NewForm.aspx?Title=YES&[something to save]
http://www.SP.com/listname/NewForm.aspx?Title=YES will load the new list item with 'Title' already filled in... but how to I save without having to press the Save button?

I am looking at users receiving an email and being able to record their 'like' or 'unlike' by having them to press a hyperlink....
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? have you searched on the [Sharepoint network](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: Can you use farm solutions? Or pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It's conceptually wrong and unsafe. GET request (clicking the link it's a `GET`, not `POST`) must be idempotent and must be read only action.
But if you really want to do this - you must add webpart to page, wich will create item relying on url parameters. It may be custom web part with server code or just Content Editor Web Part with javascript code using CSOM (if you on 2010 or 2013 SharePoint).